# How do you print a string along side regular text to make it look like it's being typed?

Tags: string, variables, printing, printf

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I'm fairly new to coding and I don't know how else to describe my problem. So what I'm trying to do is print a line of text that says "Welcome (playerName) to THE DUNGEON!" but I'm using a function to print it out in sequence to make it look like it's being type out. The only thing is that I can't figure out how to make it work with a string variable sandwiched between regular text. The function takes the text and prints it out letter by letter with a 45ms delay to make it look like it's being typed out. I just don't know how to implement the variable into it.

```
void typeText(const std::string& text){
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << text[i] << flush;
    Sleep(45);
}


int main(){
string playerName;
cout << "What is your name?\n";
cin >> playerName;

typeText("Welcome "(playerName) " to THE DUNGEON!\n");
Sleep(3000);
typeText("The game will be starting in 3 seconds.\n");
Sleep(3000);
clear();
```

I tried to use it like the printf function but that didn't seem to work. So at the moment I'm kind of stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you *can* concatenate string *literals* (i.e. "abc""def" will be the same as "abcdef"), you *can't* concatenate string *variables* simply by writing them next to each other.

Thus, the following line generates errors (which aren't necessarily that easy to understand):

```cpp
typeText("Welcome "(playerName) " to THE DUNGEON!\n");
```

However, you can concatenate `std::string` variables using the [`+` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B); so, that line should be changed to this:

```cpp
typeText("Welcome " + playerName + " to THE DUNGEON!\n");
```

Here is a working version of your code, with the relevant headers included and the `clear()` function replaced with the more conventional, `system("cls")` (I also corrected the 'typos' with missing closing braces after your `typeText` and `main` functions):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void typeText(const std::string& text)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << text[i] << std::flush;
        Sleep(45);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string playerName;
    std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
    std::cin >> playerName;

    typeText("Welcome " + playerName + " to THE DUNGEON!\n");
    Sleep(3000);
    typeText("The game will be starting in 3 seconds.\n");
    Sleep(3000);
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

See also: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

---

PS: If you want the parentheses around the player's name, then add them at the end/start of the surrounding literals:

```cpp
typeText("Welcome (" + playerName + ") to THE DUNGEON!\n");
```

Comment: wow that was so simple. Thank you! I will look into not using the std namespace as well.